# How to find .php files with numbers in the filename

Tags: command-line, find

I've been having files being included in one of my systems. An example of these is `default76.php`

Most times there are just 2 digits before the extension.

I need a way to find these files and print them out.

Comment: most times just 2 digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the number of digits before the extension is not fixed, using `find`:

```
find /path/to/target/directory -type f -regextype posix-basic -regex '.*[0-9]\.php'
```

If you need to match the extension case-insensitively:

```
find /path/to/target/directory -type f -regextype posix-basic -iregex '.*[0-9]\.php'
```

```
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % tree
.
├── file100.php
├── file10.php
├── file1.php
├── file1.PHP
└── foo

0 directories, 5 files
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % find . -type f -regextype posix-basic -regex '.*[0-9]\.php'
./file1.php
./file10.php
./file100.php
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % find . -type f -regextype posix-basic -iregex '.*[0-9]\.php'
./file1.php
./file10.php
./file1.PHP
./file100.php
```

Comment: Thanks @kos. Now I'm only left with the file results which exactly what i wanted. Removed all the directories that have numbers in their file names

Answer (score 0):

This is a crude way of doing it:

```
cd /path/to/your/php/files
find . -type f | grep '\.php$' | grep '[0-9]'
```

It wouldn't work right if you have digits in the directory names but otherwise should be OK.

Comment: @smurf Thank you for that. It gives me good results. I've tweaked it as below to remove the directory results as you'd mentioned  

`find /path/ -type f | grep \\.php$ | grep '[0-9]'`

Comment: Is there a way i can omit directories from the results?

Comment: The problem with this is that it will match also files ending with `.php` with a number everywhere in the filename, e.g. `1foo.php`.

Comment: Thats a true observation @kos. I was getting results regardless of where the numbers are and if the directory has the number

Comment: @MichaelBuluma Yes, to be more precise this matches files ending with `.php` with a path everywhere in the *path*. It could be fixed by removing the last `grep` (which is redundant) and changing the first `grep` to `grep '[0-9]\.php$'`: `find . -type f | grep '[0-9]\.php$'`.

Comment: @kos this works perfectly. Now to put it on the real test. Thanks a lot